# Trying to use rspec, but getting an error that rspec-core 2.2.1 has been activated, but my Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec

I've update my gems.  I've created a sample Rails app and have the following in my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

However, when I run 'rspec spec/', I get the following message:

```
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': 
You have already activated rspec-core 2.2.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.1.0. 
Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 11):

try using `bundle update rspec` and `bundle update rspec-rails`. your `Gemfile.lock` file, located in the root directory, is probably specifying a version number for each gem.

Answer (score 8):

A combination of Sam Ritchie's and Alexey's solutions helped me here.  In the end I had to:

```
bundle update rspec
bundle update rspec-rails
sudo gem uninstall rspec-mocks
sudo gem uninstall rspec-expectations
sudo gem uninstall rspec-core
```

(prompts for versions if none are entered)

As Alexey says, use this to see which versions are too high:

```
gem list rspec
```

(Would vote for you Alexey, but apparently I don't have enough of a "reputation" on stack.)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue right now. to fix it try to:

```
sudo gem uninstall rspec-core -v 2.2.1
bundle update rspec-core
```

You may need to do that for other dependent gems (like rspec, rspec-rails etc). Use the command to see the candidates:

```
gem list rspec
```

Comment: This fixed it. The problem for me was that I had installed rspec twice as local gems - once without specifying a version number, and once with specifying a version number. 

Rspec installed with a version number was lower than the one installed without a version number, and it was trying to load the rspec-support gem with a higher version number than required.

TL;DR: remove duplicate gems - run gem list rspec to see which ones are duplicates and then remove these versions.

Answer (score 0):

Rails noob here ... I'm following Michael Hartl's brilliant tutorial ... stuck at [layouts](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:layouts)

Tried changing rspec & webrat versions as mentioned in [this post about rspec/webrat errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517724/rspec-is-giving-an-error-with-my-layout-links-from-the-rails-tutorial-failure-e) to no avail.

For rspec v2.1.0 I get the same error as @user338413.

rspec -v returns 2.2.1

---

dev machine running ubuntu 10.04

resolved....works with rspec 2.2.0 + webrat 0.7.1, although I would still like to know why

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

will force bundler to use the gem version you are requiring for your project, ignoring system-wide settings.

Answer (score 0):

change the version number from 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 in Gemfile.lock