# install ruby on rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to run an application built in ruby on rails. I have installed ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2.1, gem 1.8.15, Netbeans 6.8, glassfish v3, jdk6u30 and mysql but still, I can't get it run.

How do I install ruby on rails on WindowsXP?

Comment: Try http://www.railsinstaller.org/. Uninstall everything and then install Railsinstaller.

Comment: thanks for your help. But by using Railsinstaller, is it possible to connect with mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to code on Windows at work and deploy to Linux and this is what I use

1. [Ruby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
2. [Ruby Dev Kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/news/2011/12/29/updated-devkit-tdm-32-4-5-2-released/)
3. [Install Rubygems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3)
4. Open a Ruby command prompt for the next steps
5. gem install bundler
6. bundle install mysql
7. bundle install rails
8. Go to the directory you want to house your rails apps (e.g. cd \rails_source)
9. rails new  (inserting the app name you want)
10. Once that is done, cd into the  directory
11. Edit Gemfile to ask for gem 'mysql'
12. cd Config
13. edit Database.yaml to look for mysql db
14. cd ..
15. create a db for your mysql instance called _development
16. Go back to rails command line
17. bundle exec rails g scaffold  (like blog_entry)
18. bundle exec rake db:migrate
19. bundle exec rake routes
20. Look for your desired route in the output
21. bundle exec rails s
22. Open a browser
23. Go to http://localhot:3000/
24. You should see a plain app

You can also check out [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) which is a visual tutorial. It is not windows oriented but it helps fill in the gaps

Answer (score 0):

I think its a quite simple to install ROR with mysql database on windows.

Follow the below instruction

1. Install Mysql Server 5.6 from [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/] , use 32bit for XP and 64Bit for W7.
2. Go to mysql/bin folder under Program Files and copy and set the path in environment variable.Open command propmt and type mysql in order to check if mysql is installed correctly.
3. If still problem with Mysql, open run and type services.msc and check for MySQL service is started or not if not start manually.
4. Download ruby2.0.0, devkit 64-32 from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
5. Download mysql connector from [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/] and make sure the version should be "(mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip)", you will find in "Looking for previous GA versions?".
6. Install ruby in C folder and select add path to executable while installing in first/second prompt.
7. Create folder devkit and extract devkit into it.
8. Extract mysql connector in C folder.
9. Open command Prompt and type ruby -v in order to check if ruby is installed, if not check ruby/bin path have to be added in environment variable.
10. Go to devkit folder, where you have extracted devkit, open command prompt and type ruby dk.rb init and then ruby dk.rb install.
11. Now we go through test, follow the instruction is given in test installation section in https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit and check with command starts with gem and ruby.
12. Create directory called dev and go inside it and type command gem install rails.
13. rails new app -d mysql2
14. Run command "bundle config build.mysql2 --no-ri --no-rdoc -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector[select what folder name is there for mysql connector]".
15. bundle install.
16. If still problem is exist, delete app folder and repeat command rails new app -d mysql2 again.
17. Go to app folder and use command rails server to start  services. Check in browser with localhost:3000.
18. To create DB, use rake db:create in app folder.

Hope it helps.