# Getting error on command "bundle install mysql"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install rails to run an app, and I'm using the directions from a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189628/install-ruby-on-rails-on-windows)

but when i try to do the step 
"bundle install mysql" I'm getting the error "ERROR: 'bundle install' was called with arguments["mysql"]
Usage:"bundle install"

I would love to get some help...

Comment: it is either:

"bundle install" or "gem install mysql"

Comment: Please post the full command you type.

Answer (score 2):

As @bjhaid pointed out, you type either

```
bundle install
```

or

```
gem install <package>
```

`bundle install` is for installing all packages listed in the `Gemfile`.