# How to install Ruby on Rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, installation

How do I install Ruby on Rails on Windows Operating System? I am new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install ruby on rails on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189628/install-ruby-on-rails-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete Installation process and set environment on windows and set git configuration:

**step 1:**
**Download links:**

A. ruby on rails: visit http://railsinstaller.org/en
 and [download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.1.0.exe)

B. nodejs: visit
https://nodejs.org/download/ and [download](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5-x86.msi)

1. run and install  `railsinstaller.exe`

2.run and install `node.exe` (optional)

**step 2:** **set environment path:**

**a. go: `my computer > properties`**

[image]

**b. Then `Advanced system settings`**
[image]

**c. Then `Environment Variables`**
[image]

**d. Then `Edit` (here you need to edit path)**
[image]

**e. add `C:\nodejs;` to path**

[image]

Test: 
1. Restart your pc (optional)
2. open your terminal (Git Bash or cmd )
3. type & hit enter:

```
ruby -v
rails -v
git --version
node -v
```

[image]

4. if you see the versions that means everything ok.

You can Set git configuration:

```
$ git config --global user.name "your github username"
$ git config --global user.email email@example.com
```

if you want to set github ssh you can see 
[Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.0/user/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-windows)

if you want to install mysql and `gem 'mysql2'`  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7)

if you want to install postgresql and gem 'pg' see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086654/installing-postgres-on-windows-for-use-with-ruby-on-rails)